# Android deep linking not working on webview

Tags: android, html, webview, deep-linking

I'm facing an issue with deep linking and Android filters. This is the manifest's intent part.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="deeplink"
        android:scheme="myapp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And when I try to open the app with a regular link it works in the Android Chrome, but not in the webview (always same "err_unknown_url_scheme")

```
<a href="myapp://deeplink/?action=showStore=001">Open in app</a>
```

I read [Android documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) on intents, and also tried something like this, but I'm not sure if it is correct

```
<a href="intent://deeplink/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.example.myapp;action=showStore=001;end">Open in app</a>
```

I only have access to the HTML code, not the Android app code. My goal is to click that link and open myapp. All stackoverflow questions about this topic are Android development related or other posts over internet are a little bit old-fashioned.

Much appreciated!

Comment: You should remove the 'action' part and move it to the intent part. `<a href="intent://deeplink?showStore=001/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.example.myapp;end">Open in app</a>`

Comment: @SimonMarquis is not working in webview, I'll comback to the developers of the app, your intent looks good and works outside the webview. Thanks!

Comment: For webviews, it must be handled on the WebView client side (shouldHandleUrl method or similar)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
please try below example which will open your application from webview.


    public class HTMLActvity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private WebView mWebView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_htmlactvity);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            String customHtml = "<a href=\"https://www.example.com\">Open in app</a>";
            mWebView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }

    deep link activity register for www.example.com

  <activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

please let me know if these doesen't work for you.

Comment: Thank you jitesh, the problem as I said I do not have access to the app code, I'm the developer of the web page... I'll comeback to the developers with your example, looks great to me, thank you!

Comment: Haven't got enough reputation yet, sorry 